# CSS padding distance?

Tags: html, css

Free Code Camp defines padding as the distance between the elements of a container and its borders.

In this example (https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/responsive-web-design/basic-css/add-different-padding-to-each-side-of-an-element

```css
.injected-text {
  margin-bottom: -25px;
  text-align: center;
}

.box {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.yellow-box {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
}

.red-box {
  background-color: crimson;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.blue-box {
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<h5 class="injected-text">margin</h5>

<div class="box yellow-box">
  <h5 class="box red-box">padding</h5>
  <h5 class="box blue-box">padding</h5>
</div>
```

The padding of the element (the word in white "padding") seems to be correct on all of values (top, down, left) except for the *right direction*; the (padding-right) is supposedly 20px which is equal to the (padding-bottom) but there is a huge difference between the 2 distances.

What am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The padding for bottom and right are exactly the same. There isn't a huge difference at all. What are you seeing?

Comment: Add `display:inline-block;` - by default `h5` is a block element, which makes it full width.

Comment: The text is centred, so the example is rather misleading. If you inspect the element in the dev console (and hover the element), you should be able to see padding more effectively.

Comment: Start using your developer tools. See this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lbic.jpg you can hover the box at bottom-right corner in developer tools and then you can see the different areas. (What you didn't see is the width of the box is changed depending on screen width. The padding remains to 20px!)

Comment: Because padding-right and padding-left should have the same value "40px". But once  padding-left is 40, it's pushing the text to the other side.

Comment: @Mari the padding shouldn't be the same. This is an exercise on Free Code camp. The values are correct. What the OP is seeing is the text centered within the container.

Comment: @DBS it seems like it + I have finished the curriculum and it never mentioned this "display: inline; " property, thank you everyone anyway, it seems I will have to find another source that covers the positioning more extensively, any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the `h5` cascades to a `display: block` which causes the element to span the available distance (minus `padding` of course). Try adding :

```
display: unset
```

to the `.red-box` class and see if it looks like more like you were expecting.

Answer (score 0):

The padding is correct, but you can't see the padding left and right because the text-align is centred.

Add the following and you will see the correct padding to the left in the green box, and the correct padding to the right in the orange box.

```
...
 .green-box {
    background-color: lime;
    padding-left: 20px;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .orange-box {
     background-color: orange;
     padding-right: 20px;
     text-align: right;
  }
 </style>
 <h5 class="injected-text">margin</h5>

<div class="box yellow-box">
  <h5 class="box red-box">padding</h5>
  <h5 class="box blue-box">padding</h5>
  <h5 class="box green-box">padding</h5>
  <h5 class="box orange-box">padding</h5>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I have a complete Github repo with all answers to FreeCodeCamp!

https://github.com/Laaouatni/FreeCodeCamp-Responsive-Web-Design

> use this if you need some help, the code there is 100% working because I do it also :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <style>
    .injected-text {
      margin-bottom: -25px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .box {
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: black;
      border-width: 5px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .yellow-box {
      background-color: yellow;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    
    .red-box {
      background-color: crimson;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 20px;
    }
    
    .blue-box {
      background-color: blue;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 20px;
    }
  </style>
  <h5 class="injected-text">margin</h5>

  <div class="box yellow-box">
    <h5 class="box red-box">padding</h5>
    <h5 class="box blue-box">padding</h5>
  </div>
</body>

</html>

<!-- Adjust the Padding of an Element Now let's put our Cat Photo App away for a little while and learn more about styling HTML. You may have already noticed this, but all HTML elements are essentially little rectangles. Three important properties control
the space that surrounds each HTML element: padding, border, and margin. An element's padding controls the amount of space between the element's content and its border. Here, we can see that the blue box and the red box are nested within the yellow box.
Note that the red box has more padding than the blue box. When you increase the blue box's padding, it will increase the distance (padding) between the text and the border around it. Change the padding of your blue box to match that of your red box. -->
```